# Add content type filter on taxonomy page

Tags: views

I am new to drupal, i have created 2 different content types i.e. Online and Offline. I want to add content type filter dropdown on taxonomy page to select any one content type from online/ offline. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating the two different content type i.e. online and offline, you should create vocabulary with two terms and then add "term reference" field to that content type.

Comment: I have different fields for both types

Comment: Create taxonomy view and then expose the content type filter with expose operator i.e. Allow user to choose the operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the views module to create the taxonomy listing. Within Views you can add an exposed filter, which allows users to select which content to view, Offline or Online.

There are many guides on views, so I wont go into the actual detail of how to configure the view itself.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `taxonomy` by adding `vocabulary` : modes(say). Add terms in it. "*Online*".
Add second term : "*Offline*". Now create field in your `entity` - content type/taxonomy wherever you want and add a field of type `term reference`. Choose `widget` select list. Now choose your vocabulary name from select list. And this way you can achieve the result.

If still having any issue you can ask.

Comment: I want display dropdown or multselect on frontend page then user can select any content type or both.

Comment: To display data - you have `views` and `exposed filters` in filter criteria.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me steps to add this option in left side bar

Comment: which option in left side bar?? You have separate regions defined in blocks. From there you can choose left side bar. Or clarify more what exactly you are asking?

Comment: I have two content types i.e. online and offline, and want to display dropdown or multiselect of online and offline in left sidebar, frontend user can find content based on content types i.e Online/ Ofline

Comment: Use taxonomy term reference.